# How to control All print jobs on a PrintServer using PrintServer class and PrintQueue class

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to C# and I have been assigned to control print jobs (pause, authenticate, resume ) on a print server that has almost 50 IP printers connected to it.

Now, I can pause and access details of print jobs of a particular printer on my development PC using printServer class at run time, like:

```
PrintServer myprintServer = new PrintServer();

foreach (var job in myprintServer.GetPrintQueue("printerA").GetPrintJobInfoCollection()) 

job.pause();
```

While my program is running and print job comes for lets say printerB or printerC they dont get controlled. I would have to run separate loops for all which is not possible.

Is there any way to control and pause all print jobs whether they come for printerA, b, c etc which are received on a print server and check for authentication. Either I havent found needed methods in `System.Printing` namespace or task cant be achieved.

Answer (score 2):

[`GetPrintQueues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printserver.getprintqueues%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should return a collection of all print queues on a printer:

```
PrintServer myprintServer = new PrintServer();

foreach (var queue in myprintServer.GetPrintQueues)
    foreach (var job in queue.GetPrintJobInfoCollection()) 
        job.pause();
```

Note that there's an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms552938%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes a list of valid print queue types

Or use `SelectMany` from Linq:

```
    foreach (var job in queue.GetPrintQueues.SelectMany(q => GetPrintJobInfoCollection()) 
        job.pause();
```